# Circled not equal sign

Tags: symbols, math-operators

How can I create a circled not equal sign similar to the image below?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\begin{document}
\[ E\Circled{\ne}m\,c^3\]
\end{document}` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a solution with a smaller `\not` bar, so the symbol is completely enclosed in the circle without the circle being too large.

Edit: I added another solution. The `\circneqrel` command provides a circled `\neq` symbol which is spaced as a binary relation symbol, considering the circle as the limits of the symbol (this is the first solution I posted). The `\circneq` command provides a similar symbol, but adjusting the spacing as if it was a simple `\neq` symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\newcommand{\newneq}{\clipbox{0pt 1.5pt 0pt 1.5pt}{$\neq$}}
\newlength{\bigcirclength}
\newlength{\neqlength}
\settowidth{\bigcirclength}{$\bigcirc$}
\settowidth{\neqlength}{$\neq$}
\newcommand{\circneqrel}{\mathrel{\makebox{$\bigcirc$\hspace*{-\bigcirclength}\makebox[\bigcirclength]{\newneq}}}}
\newcommand{\circneq}{\mathrel{\makebox{\makebox[\neqlength]{$\bigcirc$}\hspace*{-\neqlength}$\newneq$}}}
\begin{document}
\( E \circneqrel mc^3 \)

\( E \circneq mc^3 \)

\( E \neq mc^3 \)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

While one may quibble about the small overlap, this approach has two advantages: 1) the spacing of `\necirc` is the same as that of `\ne` and 2) it works across math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\necirc{\mathrel{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\SavedStyle\ne}{\SavedStyle\bigcirc}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}}}}}
\begin{document}
$E\ne mc^3$

$E \necirc mc^3$

$\scriptstyle E\ne mc^3$

$\scriptstyle E \necirc mc^3$

$\scriptscriptstyle E\ne mc^3$

$\scriptscriptstyle E \necirc mc^3$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here are two solutions: one with `\stackinset` command from the `stackengine` package, with `\bigcirc` and a slightly reduced version of `\neq`, and another with the recent package `circledsteps`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{circledsteps}

\newcommand{\circledneq}{\mathrel{\stackMath\stackinset{c}{0pt}{c}{0pt}{\scalebox{0.75}{$\neq $}}{\bigcirc}}}
\newcommand{\Circledneq}{\pgfkeys{/csteps/inner ysep=2.5pt, /csteps/inner xsep=2.5pt}\mathrel{\Circled{\neq}} }

\begin{document}

$E\circledneq mc^3 $

$E\Circledneq mc^3 $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is only a simple solution using simple commands where I have used a predefinite symbol of the `stix` package called `\circledequal`.

[image]

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stix,cancel}
\begin{document}
\[
A \cancel{\circledequal} B, A_{\cancel{\circledequal}} B
\]
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:** With `fdsymbol` package you have the same font of Computer Modern (CM).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cancel,fdsymbol}
\begin{document}
$A\cancel{\oequal} B$
\end{document}
```